# Yelp API Parsing JSON Failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am currently developing using the Yelp API which I have working successfully on a server. Problem I am encountering is parsing the JSON output for example I am able to parse Name, Title, Phone but everything returns 'undefined' not sure what is going on.

[Yelp API Server](https://hungrymonica.com/api/yelp.php?q=la%20lucha&s=0&p=1)

Using Jquery 3.7.1 below is the code I am using which only semi-works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //AJAX / PARSE YELP
    $(document).on("click", "#search-button", function() {
        //SEARCH VALUES BELOW    
        var q = escape($('#term').val());
        var start = 0;
        var page = 1;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/yelp.php',
            data: {
                q: q,
                s: start,
                p: page
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //RETURN DATASETS      
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);

                //RETURN VALUES
                var name = obj.name; //works
                var imgmain = obj.image_url; //undefined
                var phone = obj.phone; //works
                var disphone = obj.display_phone; //undefined
                var loc1 = obj.address1; //undefined

                $('#search-out').html(obj.name + '</br>' + '<img src="' + obj.imgmain + '"/>' + '</br>' + obj.phone + '</br>' + obj.disphone + '</br>' + obj.loc1 + );
            }
        });
    }); //END 
    ///
}); //END JQUERY
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to test because when I call your url from a `fetch` function, your server returns an error: Fetch API cannot load https://hungrymonica.com/api/yelp.php?q=la%20lucha&s=0&p=1 due to access control checks. When I paste the data directly in a JS file, it works. https://jsfiddle.net/sajp5cze/1/

Comment: Honestly just weird, never encountered these random results

Comment: Based on the JSON you get, all those values should work *except* `obj.address1` because such a key doesn't exist. There is an `obj.location.address1`. https://jsbin.com/rapekemufa/1/edit?js,console So, I cannot reproduce `undefined` on `image_url` and `display_phone`, while the `undefined for the non-existent `address1` is self-explanatory.

Comment: Can you dsplay the result of console.log(data) ?